# How to know if a Scala file modified with IntelliJ Idea is saved and if it is checked into CVS?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm a long-time Eclipse user and I just now decided to try IntelliJ IDEA 9 (free edition) for Scala.

A couple of dumb questions:

- How can I tell if a file I've modified has been saved?
- How can I tell if I file I've saved has been checked into CVS?

I feel incredibly "exposed" to some sort of imminent danger when I don't see the familiar visual cues from Eclipse that indicate a file has been saved and/or checked in.

Thanks

Comment: Notice, too, that the only `Save` command is `Save All`. Some find this unnerving, but it's meant to ensure consistency of the on-disk file state when using refactorings that simultaneously modify multiple files.

Answer (score 13):

In IDEA 11:

`Settings->Editor->Editor Tabs->Mark modified tabs with asterisk`

**UPDATE**

In IDEA 15:

`Settings->Editor->General->Editor Tabs->Mark modified tabs with asterisk`

Answer (score 8):

Under `Settings -> IDE Settings -> General -> Synchronization` you can control when files are saved. I save files on Frame Deactivation (that is, switching to another program), and after 60 seconds of idle time.

You should also look at the [Local History](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/local_history.html) feature, which is a local VCS for your project, capturing all the individual edits between commits. This allows you to roll back changes that were made by the auto-save feature, which some people find unnerving at first.

Answer (score 4):

If a file is modified but not saved, there's an asterisk, `*`, in its tab.

If a file is newer than its VCS counterpart, its name is displayed in dark blue instead of black. If it is not under VCS at all, it is shown in dark red. This goes for the editor tab as well as other places such as the Project window.

Comment: You have to enable the asterisk in the settings dialog (Ctrl+Shift+S, search for "modified"). It is turned off by default.

Comment: I cannot edit the comment any longer but as an addition to the colors in the project view you can also press Alt+9 to bringup the changes tab which shows all modified and unversioned or pending files.

Comment: We must be using different versions... I'm on 9.0.1 and I'm not able to see ANY of the stuff described above.